# Java - ArrayList containing ArrayLists of different types

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'd like to prefix this question by saying I am very new to coding, and that everything I know about coding I have taught myself and that this is my first program and question.

Now let's get to it.

Say I have these seven classes:

```
public class Animal(){
// methods and variables
} 

public class Mammal extends Animal {
// inherited methods + new methods
}

public class Reptile extends Animal {
// inherited methods + new methods
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
// inherited methods + new methods
}

public class Dog extends Mammal {
// Constructor assigning super.variables
//inherited methods
}

public class Snake extends Reptile {
// Constructor assigning super.variables
//inherited methods
}

public class Eagle extends Bird {
// Constructor assigning super.variables
//inherited methods
}
```

and I have these 3 ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<Mammal> mammals = new ArrayList<Mammal>();
ArrayList<Reptile> reptiles = new ArrayList<Reptile>();
ArrayList<Bird> birds = new ArrayList<Bird>();
```

And I'd like to create an ArrayList that stores the 3 Arraylists above, how would I do that?

I have tried:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Animal>(){
  {
  add(mammals);
  add(reptiles);
  add(birds);
  }
};
```

but I get a type mismatch error.

Please note: I would like to declare and initialize the ArrayLists of Lists, and, I would like to be able to call methods inside the Animals class if possible.

So, although this works:

```
     ArrayList<Object> listOfLists = new ArrayList<Object>
```

I would like to avoid using it if possible.

I would also like to avoid using:

```
ArrayList<Animal> mammals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
ArrayList<Animal> reptiles = new ArrayList<Animal>();
ArrayList<Animal> birds = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<List<? extends Animal>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(mammals, reptiles, birds);`

Comment: @shmosel Thanks so much I have spent days looking through answer to no avail!